# No device available for decoder: device type vaapi needed for codec h264

Tags: ffmpeg, raspberry-pi

I am currently trying to decode video using H/W accel on my raspberry pi 4 (Raspberry Pi OS 64bit). However it throws the following error and stops decoding

`$ /home/pi/bin/ffmpeg -hwaccel vaapi -hwaccel_device /dev/dri/renderD128 -i 'input.mkv' -c:v h264_v4l2m2m -c:a copy -b:v 8M output.mp4`

```
AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x55739baa60] libva: vaGetDriverNameByIndex() failed with unknown libva error, driver_name = (null)
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x55739baa60] Failed to initialise VAAPI connection: -1 (unknown libva error).
Device creation failed: -5.
[h264 @ 0x557401e700] No device available for decoder: device type vaapi needed for codec h264.
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (hevc (native) -> h264 (h264_v4l2m2m))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy
)
```

FFmpeg info

```
$ ffmpeg -codecs | grep h264
ffmpeg version N-105691-gc439c6b191 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10 (Debian 10.2.1-6)
  configuration: --prefix=/home/pi/ffmpeg_build --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-cflags=-I/home/pi/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/home/pi/ffmpeg_build/lib --extra-libs='-lpthread -lm' --ld=g++ --bindir=/home/pi/bin --arch=aarch64 --enable-gpl --enable-gnutls --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libwebp --enable-libdrm --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      57. 21.100 / 57. 21.100
  libavcodec     59. 21.100 / 59. 21.100
  libavformat    59. 17.102 / 59. 17.102
  libavdevice    59.  5.100 / 59.  5.100
  libavfilter     8. 27.100 /  8. 27.100
  libswscale      6.  5.100 /  6.  5.100
  libswresample   4.  4.100 /  4.  4.100
  libpostproc    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
 DEV.LS h264                 H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10 (decoders: h264 h264_v4l2m2m ) (encoders: libx264 libx264rgb h264_v4l2m2m h264_vaapi )

$ ffmpeg -hide_banner -hwaccels
Hardware acceleration methods:
vdpau
vaapi
drm
```

Comment: Have you seen [this post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/128345)? Sounds like you need to specify `-c:v h264_v4l2m2m` as an input option as well as the output option. You might want to post your Q on RasPi community, where you might find more informed people on the hardware.